# Prefix route with a named parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a match that render by a named parameter

```
match '/:username' => 'controller#action'
```

I also have some resourses in my "/"

```
resourses :products, :services
```

The problem is when I want to go to products the routing take 'product' as :username parameter. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Look here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#prefixing-the-named-route-helpers), you could do:

```
scope "(:username)/" do
  resources :products
end
```

Comment: this works good, but what I want is when I go to products show something like this in my url : myapp/products and also can show an username like myapp/:username. Whit this solution if I want to go to products I have to do like myapp/:username/products.

Comment: parenthesis make the parameter optionnal.

Comment: The first Answer was almost that I want, I just put the resource out of the scope and it works!
 
So if I put myapp/products it goes to products. And if I put myapp/:username it goes to some username

Comment: Can you put the first code with resources :products out the scope? So other people can see the right answer.